# Multiple RecyclerViews in ScrollView not Scrolling all the Way

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have three horizontal scrolling recycler views that are too large vertically for the app screen. To solve this, I nested them inside a NestedScrollView however the vertical scroll doesn't go all the way to the bottom of the last recycler view.

This is as far as the view will scroll:

[image: multiple_recycler_views]

Here's my config:

Container View:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/recyclerTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/recycler_with_filters"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/recyclerMiddle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/recycler_with_filters"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/recyclerBottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/recycler_with_filters"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Included layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Test!"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/didot"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_filter_inactive"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="filter1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_filter_inactive"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="filter2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_filter_inactive"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="filter3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_filter_inactive"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="filter4" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filters" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Controller:

public class TestRecyclerFragment extends Fragment {

```
public static TestRecyclerFragment newInstance() {
    return new TestRecyclerFragment();
}

private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewTop;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewMiddle;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewBottom;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapterTop;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapterMiddle;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapterBottom;


private Business[] mBusinesses = {new Business("The Tavern", 0), new Business("The Tavern1", 0), new Business("The Tavern2", 0), new Business("The Tavern3", 0), new Business("The Tavern4", 0), new Business("The Tavern5", 0), new Business("The Tavern6", 1), new Business("The Tavern7", 1), new Business("The Tavern8", 1), new Business("The Tavern9", 1), new Business("The Tavern10", 1), new Business("The Tavern11", 1)};

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_recycler, container, false);

    View recycleWithFilterTop = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTop);
    mRecyclerViewTop = recycleWithFilterTop.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    View recycleWithFilterMiddle = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerMiddle); 
    mRecyclerViewMiddle = recycleWithFilterMiddle.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    View recycleWithFilterBottom = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerBottom); 
    mRecyclerViewBottom = recycleWithFilterBottom.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); 

    mRecyclerViewTop.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerViewMiddle.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerViewBottom.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerTop = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerViewTop.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerTop);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerMiddle = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerViewMiddle.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerMiddle);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerBottom = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerViewBottom.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerBottom);

    mAdapterTop = new TestRecyclerFragment.TestAdapter(mBusinesses);
    mRecyclerViewTop.setAdapter(mAdapterTop);

    mAdapterMiddle = new TestRecyclerFragment.TestAdapter(mBusinesses);
    mRecyclerViewMiddle.setAdapter(mAdapterMiddle);

    mAdapterBottom = new TestRecyclerFragment.TestAdapter(mBusinesses);
    mRecyclerViewBottom.setAdapter(mAdapterBottom);

    return v;
}

public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Business[] businesses;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mBusinessName;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mBusinessName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.businessName);
        }
    }

    public TestAdapter(Business[] myDataset) {
        mBusinesses = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public TestAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_holder_businesses, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mBusinessName.setText(mBusinesses[position].getName());
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBusinesses.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mBusinesses[position].getViewType();
    }
}
```

}

*Edit: I think the issue has to do with the scroll not knowing how large the view is going to be at the time it draws the view. I've tried hard-coding the heights in the include like this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/recyclerTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    layout="@layout/recycler_with_filters"/>
```

However that messes up the view.

*Edit2: I've tried many of the solutions advocated in other questions on this topic including setting setting `nestedScrollingEnabling` to `false`. These solutions don't work in my instance. I'm not sure if it's a difference in my configuration or that I'm using a newer version of the NestedScrollView api.

Comment: I've tested your code, its working perfectly my side, can you please post view_holder_businesses layout file

Comment: @Barden Holt I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ShubhamAnand check my answer below about adding a dynamic height to layout params. if that doesn't work post some code and i can take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the scroll view to scroll to the bottom by adding a dynamic height to the layout params of my bottom recycler view:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerBottom = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecyclerViewBottom.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerBottom);

final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (550 * scale + 0.5f);
mRecyclerViewBottom.getLayoutParams().height = pixels;
```

Comment: What is 550 here? Is that 1 listItem's height ?

Comment: @ShubhamAnand  yea. it's kind of a hacky answer that i probably improved at some point. but it may get you on the right track.

Comment: Your solution seems to be working. Thanks. @BradenHolt

Answer (score 0):

Adding static height is not a proper solution considering different screen resolutions in the market. If you want to have multiple `Recyclerviews` scrolls as a whole inside `NestedScrollView` you should consider adding `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to `Recyclerview`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_activity_horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view_departments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I would agree that my solution is suboptimal but setting `nestedScrollingEnabled` to false doesn't affect the scroll position. There's a multitude of solutions advocating your approach so I'm not sure if it has something to do with the newer versions of the api (I'm using androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView) or my configuration, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I just added some dp to pixel conversion code that makes my solution more dynamic. It seems to be working as expected on multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code, it's working perfectly my side, Just I've added below 3 lines of code in TestRecyclerFragment onCreateView method

```
    mRecyclerViewTop.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerViewMiddle.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerViewBottom.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

You can see working demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmfmcdjw58cto4q/device-2019-09-05-115921.mp4?dl=0